# Regarding a list and map

Tags: java, list, collections, hashmap

I was doing a research let say I have below array list

```
    List list=new ArrayList();
      list.add(1);
      list.add(1);
      list.add(2);
      list.add(3);
      list.add(3);
```

Now as I can see the elements repeated in the list are 1 and 3 , now I want to create hashMap

```
Map hm = new HashMap();
```

and now in this HashMap I want key should be 1 and 3 and values should be 2 and 2 that is key 1 should have value 2 and key 3 should have value 2 that is the number of times is repeated is should be the value and the element that is repeated is to be stored as key Please advise how to achieve this..!

Comment: `System.out.println(hm)`

Comment: Please don't edit your question to ask a completely different question. It makes the answers useless. To print your map to the console, see my previous comment.

Comment: @assylias thanks dude it works..! but I was looking something related to map.entry man..!!

Comment: *"I was looking something related to map.entry"* => I'm not sure what you are asking. When you print the map, it print a list of entries in the format `{key = value}`.

Comment: @assylias ok man be cool , I was thinking for some research..!

Comment: I am not cool or uncool - I just don't understand what you are asking. If you need documentation about map.entry, have a look at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply loop over the list and:

- if the item is not in the map, create it with value = 1
- if the item already is in the map, get the value, increment increment it and put it back into the map

ps: It is good practice to use generics:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
```

and

```
Map<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer, Integer> ();
```

Comment: thanks dude , could you please post the updated code that will help in understanding a lot..!

Comment: @DON You now have the algorithm, I suggest you write the code based on that (it should not be much more than 5 lines). If you have issues, you can come back and ask a question on that specific issue.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a [`Multiset`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset), such as the one in [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com). For example:

```
Multiset<Integer> multiset = HashMultiset.create(list);
```

Then you could call `count`:

```
System.out.println(multiset.count(1)); // 2
System.out.println(multiset.count(2)); // 1
System.out.println(multiset.count(3)); // 2
```

That doesn't implement `Map`, admittedly - but I suspect it does everything you need it to.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
{
    // get a number from the list
    int number = list.get(i);

    // get the value linked to the key
    Integer mapval = hm.get(number);
    if (mapval == null)
    {
        // the value returned is null, which means that the key isn't in the map
        // the key wasn't found yet, so the number is zero times in it
        mapval = 0;
    }
    // increase the number of times the number occurs.
    hm.put(number, mapval + 1);
}
```